# If input field has no value and not focus do action with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of disabled input fields With one enabled input field at top.
**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rzyW99ZPbWcRMbDcnXrs?p=preview)**

Quick view:

[image]

If you focus on **"Name this group"** input field, first disable input field will enable with active class.

What I am wanting is if there is no value in **"Name this group"** and not focused it will go back to how it was at the first place. Means first child input will back to disable and active class will be removed again.

Any help achieving this action will highly appreciated.

My Code:

```
$scope.focusGroup = function(i) {

    $scope.csTagGrp[i].csTags[0].active = true;

  };

  $scope.focusItem = function(i, parent_i) {
    $scope.csTagGrp[parent_i].csTags[i].old = true;
    if ($scope.csTagGrp[parent_i].csTags[i + 1]) {
      $scope.csTagGrp[parent_i].csTags[i + 1].active = true;
    } else if ($scope.csTagGrp[parent_i + 1]) {
      $scope.csTagGrp[parent_i + 1].csTags[0].active = true;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some angular expressions on your second field to set the class and/or toggle ngDisabled.

```
<input type="text"
       ng-model="fieldZero"/>
<input type="text"
       ng-model="fieldOne"
       ng-class="{active: fieldZero.length > 0}"
       ng-disabled="!(fieldZero.length > 0)"/>
```